# How to disable selection of items in list in actions on google?

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I am trying to make an action on google which shows a list.I want to disable the selection in that list as I want to make it only a read only list but I am unable to do that.

I have tried creating an intent with the event actions_intent_OPTION and just returning void from it in the fulfillment using the return statement but in that case I am getting a Webhook error 206 and I cannot find another way to do this task.Can someone help me and tell me how to make a read only list in actions on google?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to disable the selection. Lists are meant to allow users select an item.

You can read more about lists and other visual selection responses in the docs - https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#visual_selection_responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable selecting from the list, but you don't have to *do* anything with the result you get.

You can treat it as bad input, as it sounds like you're trying to do, but you do need to acknowledge it in some way.

The easiest way might be to not actually create an Intent with the `actions_intent_OPTION` event and just let the default Fallback Intent handle it. That will usually say something like "I'm sorry, I didn't understand."

Better would be to create the Intent that *does* handle the event, but specifically sends back a response. The response must contain some content, but this could be SSML that contains silent audio. Even better would be a message prompting them what they can do instead of selecting something from the list.